# Replicated point patterns on linear networks in spatstat

Tags: r, spatstat

I have point pattern data from a replicated experiment where the points in each replicate are constrained to the same linear network (the data are from daily surveys of a bike path for snakes: each day gives a separate point pattern of locations where animals are found).

I know that in `spatstat` it is possible to fit point processes to multiple point patterns simultaneously (with `mppm`), and to fit point process models on linear networks (with `lppm`); is it possible to do both simultaneously? As far as I can tell, `mppm` will not accept `lpp` objects: is there another way of fitting this type of model?

Comment: What kind of model are you considering? Is it simply independent Poisson models for each replication? Are there covariates that change over time or are the covariates static? Maybe in simple Poisson cases with static covariates the model reduces to something that can be handled. To my knowledge there is no `mppm` analogue on linear networks in `spatstat` at the moment (Adrian Baddeley sometimes implements things without me noticing, but this is such a big thing, that I doubt that I would have missed it).

Comment: @EgeRubak The model I'd like to fit is a log-linear Poisson process with a spatially-varying covariate (temperature), which does change between replicates (i.e. the covariate is given by a distinct `linim` object for each replicate). Ideally, I'd like to include a random effect of replicate id as well, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet fully supported in `spatstat`.

However, you can do most of what you want by converting the `lpp` objects to quadrature schemes using `linequad` and then using these quadrature schemes instead of `ppp` objects in the hyperframe. Example:

```
X1 <- spiders
X2 <- runiflpp(25, domain(spiders))
A <- linequad(X1)
B <- linequad(X2)
f <- function(x,y)x
H <- hyperframe(X=solist(A,B), Z=list(f,f))
fit <- mppm(X ~ Z, data=H)
```

Most methods for `mppm` will work correctly; except that you can't simulate or predict the fitted model, because it doesn't know that it's supposed to be on a network.

If you have a long list of `ppp` objects, then instead of converting the point patterns to quadrature schemes one-by-one, you could use `solapply( , linequad)`.

Comment: Please contact me (using email in spatstat package) for additional code for this purpose.